# Create planet_osm_lines, planet_osm_point, ....polygon, roads

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim, osmosis

I have loaded data into a postgres database using nominatim. (Using the setup.php --osm-file planet.osm.bz2 --all ....etc...

This loaded the data and nominatim works great, however, I need to also render the data.

I see that I have a planet_osm_nodes, planet_osm_rels, and planet_osm_ways loaded in the database from the nominatim install.

Is there a way to turn these tables into the planet_osm_lines, planet_osm_point, planet_osm_polygon and planet_osm_roads tables that are needed for rendering?

I have both osm2pgsql and osmosis installed on my server and hoping maybe I can use one of these to just create these tables and index rather then doing a complete re-load of the data using osm2pgsql or osmosis.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im' afraid you will need two separate databases. While it might be possible to do geocoding and rendering using a single database it will be rather slow because both mechanisms have completely different requirements regarding their database layout.